# How to use methods like Contains, Remove or IndexOf of TObjectList<T>

Tags: delphi, equals, tobjectlist

I am having problems using methods like `Contains`, `Remove` or `IndexOf` of `TObjectList<T>` class, 
when T is a custom type like `TSocket` in the following example code.

I started by implementing a custom `TSocket` type and tried to use it in a list of type `TObjectList<TSocket>` like this:

```
list := nil;
socket := nil;
try
  list := TObjectList<TSocket>.Create();
  socket := TSocket.Create(TIpAddress.Parse('127.0.0.1'),6857);

  // add new socket object with equal values to list
  list.Add(TSocket.Create(TIpAddress.Parse('127.0.0.1'),6857));

  // should return true but returns false
  if list.Contains(socket) then
    WriteLn('socket contained in list')
  else
    WriteLn('socket not contained in list');

  // should return number 0 but returns -1
  if list.IndexOf(socket) = 0 then
    WriteLn('socket contained in list')
  else
    WriteLn('socket not contained in list');

  // should remove item from list but items doesn't get removed
  list.Remove(socket);

finally
  list.Free();
  socket.Free();
```

I expected that `Contains`, `IndexOf` and `Remove` make use of the `Equals` procedure of `TMyObject` and overwriten implementation of this procedure. Therefore I added the following implemenation of `Equals` to my TSocket class:

```
type
  TSocket = class
  strict private
    _ipAddress: TIpAddress;
    _port: integer;
  public
    constructor Create(ipAddress: TIpAddress; port: integer);
    function GetIpAddress: TIpAddress;
    function GetPort: integer;
    property IpAddress: TIpAddress read GetIpAddress;
    property Port: integer read GetPort;
    function Equals(other: TObject): boolean; overload; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TSocket.Create(ipAddress: TIpAddress; port: integer);
begin
  inherited Create();
  _ipAddress := ipAddress;
  _port := port;
end;

function TSocket.Equals(other: TObject): boolean;
var
  otherSocket: TSocket;
begin
  if not (other is TSocket) then exit(false);
  otherSocket := other as TSocket;
  result:= (_ipAddress.Equals(otherSocket.IpAddress)) and (_port = otherSocket.Port)
end;

function TSocket.GetIpAddress: TIpAddress;
begin
  result := _ipAddress;
end;

function TSocket.GetPort: integer;
begin
  result := _port;
end;

destructor TSocket.Destroy;
begin
  _ipAddress.Free();
  inherited Destroy();
end;
```

Using this code `Contains` returns false but should be true, `IndexOf` returns -1 but should be 0 and `Remove` does not remove the object but should remove it. I expected these methods would use the `Equals` method of `TSocket` which they didn't. After reading the documentation I found out that the constructor of `TObjectList` can be called with an implemenantion of IComparer. Therefore I implementated an `TEqualityComparer<TSocket>` in order to use my `Equals` method.
Unfortunately the constructor of `TObjectList` does not support the `IEqualityComparer` interface but instead use the `IComparer` interface.

**Question:**
How do I use methods like `Contains`, `Remove` or `IndexOf` of `TObjectList<T>` when using custom types in Delphi? 
In other programming languages (like Java or C#) `Equals` is used to compare objects in list types. What mechanism does Delphi use to compare objects?

**Update**
Thank you for the comprehensive feedback. I have updated my question and the code appropriately. I elaborated on what my expectations were when running the code and added further code to make my intentions clearer.
@DavidHeffernan: The implementation was indeed wrong. I added inheritance to TInterfacedObject in order to learn more about reference counting. I removed TInterfacedObject from the code.

Comment: Big problem is that you are mixing reference counted interfaces and objects. You have to stop that. Every part of code here is badly wrong. `Contains`, `Remove`, `IndexOf` work fine already with your type, but you are using the wrong type so you are going to need to start again.

Comment: Sorry if my code quality is not good I still trying to learn the language

Comment: The thing is we can answer the question but it won't help. The problem is deeper. You have chosen to use reference counted interfaces and have to stick to that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the only recounted interface I see is the comparer for the list. That is perfectly fine (albeit unnecessary in this case).

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code shown. What is the actual problem? What "*does not work*" exactly?

Comment: @remy TSocket derives from TInterfacedObject

Comment: I see many mentions in both the code comments and the text of *does not work* or *did not work*, but not a single explanation of what *not work* means specifically. If you can't clearly explain the problem you're having, you can't expect us to help you solve it. *Doesn't work as expected* only has meaning when we know what you **expected** and in what way it did not meet those expectations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, I missed that. In that case, the OP should being `TList<T>` or `TInterfaceList` instead.

Comment: When saying something "does not work", you should state the "expected behaviour" and what is the "actual behaviour". In your case it would be  reasonable to guess (a ***guess*** nonetheless) that you "expect `sockets.Contains(socket)` to return True", but it "actually returns False". (As a side-note claiming `sockets.Remove(socket)` doesn't work is pointless since it doesn't even get executed.) And finally, your MCVE is incomplete because you have failed to demonstrate how you're adding your socket to `sockets` in the first place. And this will be a critical part of whatever is wrong.

Comment: Note! `IndexOf` returns the zero-based index, thus 0 is a valid index for the first entry in the list.

Comment: You are right that is a typo, it does return -1 right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error was your assumption that `TObjectList<T>` uses the `Equals` function to test for equality.

By default, `TObjectList<T>`, or more accurately `TList<T>`, uses the comparer returned by `TComparer<T>.Default`. In the case of `TObjectList<TSocket>`, the default comparer compare the pointer itself.  Since you created 2 differents objects, the pointers differ. The result you get is the expected result.

If you want to override that default behavior, you need to supply your own comparer.  The way to do so is to pass it through the constructor like this :

```
TObjectList<TSocket>.Create(TComparer<TSocket>.Construct(
    function (const L, R : TSocket) : Integer
    begin
      //Compare here.
    end)
   );
```

Your function should:

- Return a value lower than 0 if L is lower than R.(Typically -1)
- Return a value greater than 0 if L is greater than R.(Typically 1)
- Return 0 of both are equals.

If, for whatever reasons, you want to only check for equality, you can technically do so and return either -1 or 1 when it's not equal without further comparison. That is, as long as you don't plan to sort the list or BinarySearch through it.

Comment: Thank you for your greate answer! Your last paragraph sounds to me as if Equals is not the right way to compare objects within lists, otherwise the TEqualityComparer would be allowed as constructor parameter. Is it wrong to use the Equals method? What would you check in your comparer implementation?

Comment: The job of a comparer is generally to sort a list or find an item in it.  You can't sort with just a TEqualityComparer. Since you don't seem to need the "sorting" capabilities, it would be "OK" to have your comparer return Equal(0)/Not Equal(anything but 0).
They probably didn't put a TEqualityComparer parameter because a TComparer can do just that and then some.

Comment: fwiw imho the implementations of `Contains`, `Remove` and `IndexOf` are broken by design. They are using `IComparer<T>` and not `IEqualityComparer<T>`. If they would use `IEqualityComparer<T>` they would in fact use the virtual `Equals` method from `TObject` for types of T that are classes (see `System.Generics.Defaults.Equals_Class`).

Comment: I thought so myself but didn't dare to say it

Comment: I wouldn't call it broken. Broken = Doesn't work.  Here, it does work perfectly, just not as you expect it to. If it relied on TObject.Equals method instead of TComparer, it would be pretty limitating. I, for one, prefer the current design.